# Dynamic Set of Fields in Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I have tried several different ways of searching for this information with no luck so far...

Firstly, I am using Access 2013, and I wouldn't exactly call myself experienced with it...

I have a table with many fields and I want to be able to create a report dynamically that only uses a subset of those fields. The subset is to be determined by a ListBox (with multi select turned on) containing the list of all of the fields.

So, a user will:

1. Opens the filtering form that was created
2. Selects the fields they wish to view
3. Clicks "Generate Report"
4. The report will only shown the fields that were asked for

Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: put all the fields on your report and set the visible property to match the checked items in the listBox

Comment: Wouldn't that give me a bunch of blank empty space where the unused columns would be?

Comment: Not quite what I'm looking for then. Perhaps I should have been more specific.

Comment: can you post an example of what they would select and how you'd like the report to look?

Comment: It's a list of fields, if they select fields A, B, C and Z, then the report would only have 4 columns, all next to one another. If they select A, D, Q, and R it would still have 4 columns, all next to one another.

Comment: do they always select 4 columns?  You can have a list of controls with values like '1st selected field,' '2nd selected field,' but you still have to design your report to handle the worst case ('n selected field')

Comment: n selected fields is the norm. I don't plan to know how many they select. I think I'm going to have to create a report using VBA...?

Comment: no, VBA won't help.  You'll have to create a report to handle all of the columns being selected.  Maybe you want to change their x-positions and widths at runtime?

Comment: I have the feeling that an export to **Excel** would suit your requirement better than a report. An arbitrary number of column is much better to handle in a sheet than on fixed width paper.

Comment: I agree with Andre451 - creating your report in Excel will give you the flexibility and control that you need to create the desired report. I do all my reports to Excel these days.